# Missing AnimationAction type definition in recent Three.js versions

Tags: typescript, three.js

I am working on a 3D real-time web app, using Python, Typescript, Three.js, etc.

I used Three.js 0.93 for months. Recently I upgraded Three.js to 0.111.
It has it's own type definition, thus, I removed `@types/three` dependency from `package.json`.

While fixing type errors, I found that `THREE.AnimationAction` is missing in the newer type definition. The error message is:

```
[myproj]/node_modules/three/src/Three"' has no exported member 'AnimationAction'.ts(2694)
```

I modified `Three.d.ts` manually like this so was able to fix that error:

```
$ echo "export * from './animation/AnimationAction';" >> node_modules/three/src/Three.d.ts
```

Is there another proper way to fix this? Any fixed version of Three.js exists?

Comment: `AnimationAction` is not public accessible anymore, see https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/17877. If you have objections against this decision, please post directly at github.

Comment: Thanks for your clear comment. I will try to drop `AnimationAction` dependency of my project.